# A Fractional Year

Tags: code-golf, date

***My PPCG holiday is over :D***

### Intro

Fractional time is `the year + (the value (minute of year) / number of minutes in the year)`.

### Example calculation

*You should assume that February always has 28 days and the year is always 365 days long.*

Let's say we want to convert the time: `17:34 3rd March 2013` to fractional time. Firstly, you find how many minutes were in 2013: [525600 minutes](http://convertwizard.com/365-days-to-minutes). Let's call this `x`.

Next, you want to find out how many minutes there have been since the start of 2013. A few quick calculations will tell you that the answer is 88894 minutes:

There have been 61 days since the start of the year, which times 1440 (number of minutes in a day) equals 87840 minutes. In 17 hours are 1020 minutes (17*60). Now, we can add 87840, 1020 and 34 minutes to equal 88894 minutes.

Let's call this `y`.

Finally, you divide `y` by `x` and add the year, resulting in `2013.16912` (to 5 decimal places).

### Input

The date and time will be given as a single string. The string will be in the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm
```

The time will always be in 24 hour format and the year will always be in the range 1900-2050 inclusive.

### Examples

```
Input:  2016-08-06 23:48
Output: 2016.59723

Input:  2013-03-03 17:34
Output: 2013.16912

Input:  1914-11-11 11:11
Output: 1914.86155
```

If you are going for the bounty, either ping me in the comments or in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

### Challenge

Calculate the given date and time as a fractional year.

Give all output to five decimal places (you may round in anyway you wish: flooring, ceiling, or true rounding). Shortest code wins.

### Bounty

**I am offering a 100 rep bounty** for the shortest program which *also* accepts the date in fractional year format and returns the time in `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` format. In essence, your program (or function) has to act in the following way:

```
f('1914-11-11 11:11') => 1914.86155
f('1914.86155')       => 1914-11-11 11:11
```

1. [t-clausen.dk - 154 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89141/30525)
2. [Neil - 183 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88941/30525)

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=88924,OVERRIDE_USER=30525;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Perhaps taking the date and time as an input would allow for test cases and easier checking?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to whether this takes into account leap years given `For this, assume February has 28 days and the year is 365 days long.`, but also `... using the Gregorian calendar.`

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon No, it does not take into account leap years

Comment: can we give more than five decimal places?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon No

Comment: Is it okay if the output is rounded off to the nearest hundredth-thousandth, i.e. input `2016-08-06 23:48` returns `2016.59724` instead of `2016.59723`?

Comment: @R.Kap Yes, that's fine

Comment: @βετѧΛєҫαγ Is it ok to handle leap years with February having 29 days? ([@t-clausen.dk's comment for reference](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88924/a-fractional-year/89027#comment217323_88941))

Comment: @pajonk No, leap years should not be handled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TSQL, 63 bytes

This is a shorter version than my original answer, because my initial answer included calculation for leap year.

```
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(16) ='1914-11-11 11:11'
    
PRINT LEFT(YEAR(@)+DATEDIFF(mi,0,STUFF(@,1,4,1900))/525600.,10)
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1656730/a-fractional-year)**

The following sql can handle both input types

## TSQL, 154 bytes

```
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(16) ='1914-11-11 11:11'--can be replaced with '1914.86155'

PRINT IIF(isdate(@)=1,LEFT(YEAR(@)+DATEDIFF(mi,0,STUFF(@,1,4,1900))/525600.,10),LEFT(@,4)+RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(16),DATEADD(mi,1*RIGHT(@,5)*5.256,0),20),12))
```

**[Combined Fiddle 1](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/522545/a-fractional-year)**

**[Combined Fiddle 2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/522543/a-fractional-year)**

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 84 bytes

```js
f=
s=>(Date.parse(1970+s.slice(4).replace(/ /,'T')+'Z')/31536e6+parseInt(s)).toFixed(5)
;
```

```html
<input placeholder=Input oninput=o.value=f(this.value)><input placeholder=Output id=o>
```

Assuming no leap years or DST are required, I replace the year with 1970 which makes `Date.parse` directly return the time offset in milliseconds, of which there were `31536000000` in 1970 (or indeed any other non-leap year). All I need do then is to add back the year and round to 5 decimal places. Edit: Bidirectional conversion in <s>183</s> 178 bytes:

```js
f=
s=>/:/.test(s,m=31536e6)?(Date.parse(1970+s.slice(4).replace(/ /,'T')+'Z')/m+parseInt(s)).toFixed(5):s.slice(0,4)+new Date(s.slice(4)*m+3e4).toJSON().slice(4,16).replace(/T/,' ')
;
```

```html
<input placeholder=Input oninput=o.value=f(this.value)><input placeholder=Output id=o>
```

Assumes strings containing a `:` are time format, handled as above, otherwise strips off the year, converts to milliseconds, adds half a minute for rounding purposes, converts to a date in 1970, extracts the month, day, hour and minute, and prefixes the original year.

Comment: @βετѧΛєҫαγ Yes, `s` is the argument to the function.

Comment: Doesn't this give invalid output, because the challenge explicitly asks for Feb to only have 28 days, and 365 days per year total?

Comment: @TimmyD sometimes february has 29 days. *Let's assume* doesn't mean it is dissallowed to handle leap years correctly

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Sorry, I meant that leap years should not be handled

Comment: @βετѧΛєҫαγ Now using neither leap years nor DST, and also has a reversible version. Is that satisfactory?

Comment: @Neil Yes, this is perfect

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab, <s>132</s> 115 bytes

```
 d=input('');m=cumsum([-1 '# #"#"##"#"'-4]);year(d)+fix((((m(month(d))+day(d))*24+hour(d))*60+minute(d))/5.256)/10^5
```

*Rounds towards 0.*

Hmmm... That's quite long.
That's using some builtins, but not the really helpful ones - because of leap years.

Parsing the string directly gives 2 more byte solution:

```
d=sscanf(input(''),'%d%[- :]');m=cumsum([-1 '# #"#"##"#"'-4]);d(1)+fix((((m(d(3))+d(5))*24+d(7))*60+d(9))/5.256)/10^5
```

Newer Matlab versions probably have some better split function, but I'm running on 2012a.

*Some bytes saved thanks to [@Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)*

Comment: You can define the array with `[-1 '# #"#"##"#"'-4]` to save a few bytes. Are `year` etc standard functions? If you are using a toolbox you should indicate it in the title, e.g. "Matlab with Financial Toolbox"

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm not familiar with the `#`-notation and never even encountered it. Where can I read more about it (quick Google search didn't help)? I think the `year` etc. are standard functions, but I don't know if they behave the same outside the toolbox [(docs)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/year.html).

Comment: It's not special notation. It's just a string with characters that have the appropriate ASCII codes to produce the required numbers. As for the functions, I didn't know, thanks for clarifying. Matlab 15b doesn't seem to have them

Comment: Oh, that's clever.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v3+, 131 bytes

```
$t=date $args[0];$a=1440*!!(date "2-29-$($t.year)");"{0:F5}"-f((($t.DayOfYear-1)*1440+$t.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes-$a)/525600+$t.Year)
```

Takes input `$args[0]` and converts it with `Get-Date` to store into .NET `[datetime]` format, stores into `$t`. Calculates whether February 29th exists, and sets `$a` so we subtract out that date's worth of minutes (if present).

Then we use the `-f`ormat operator with a [fixed-string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString) specification of 5 decimal digits to run through the calculation. Uses built-ins to calculate the `.DayOfYear` and the `.TotalMinutes` of the given input, subtract `$a` if it's a leap year, divide by `525600` minutes total, and add on the input `.Year`.

Will complain (verbosely) to STDERR if February 29th doesn't exist (see examples below), but since STDERR is ignored by default, we don't worry about that. Also, note that PowerShell does [banker's rounding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx#Midpoint) by default.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\fractional-year.ps1 '2016-08-06 23:48'
2016.59724

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\fractional-year.ps1 '2013-03-03 17:34'
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "2-29-2013" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing\fractional-year.ps1:7 char:36
+   $t=date $args[0];$a=1440*!!(date "2-29-$($t.year)");"{0:F5}"-f((($t.DayOfYear- ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

2013.16913

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\fractional-year.ps1 '1914-11-11 11:11'
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "2-29-1914" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing\fractional-year.ps1:7 char:36
+   $t=date $args[0];$a=1440*!!(date "2-29-$($t.year)");"{0:F5}"-f((($t.DayOfYear- ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

1914.86155
```

---

#### Alternately, with leap years, 119 bytes

```
"{0:F5}"-f((($t=date $args[0]).DayOfYear-1+$t.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes/1440)/(date "12-31-$($t.year)").DayOfYear+$t.Year)
```

If we follow calendar settings, we can shave off a dozen bytes because we won't need to account for `$a` in the original code above. This allows us to move `$t` into the expression itself, and we'll explicitly calculate the `.DayOfYear` for December 31st. Otherwise, follows the same methodology.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>163</s> 173 bytes

more bytes because of output format

doesn't use any date builtins, like the java answer.

```
def s(x):z=x[5:10].split("-");v=x[10:].split(":");return int(x[:4])+(sum(([-1,31,28]+[31,30,31,30,31]*2)[:int(z[0])],int(z[1]))*1440+int(v[0])*60+int(v[1]))/525600
```

slightly more readable

```
def s(x):
    date=x[5:10].split("-");time=x[10:].split(":")
    return int(x[:4])+(sum(([-1,31,28]+[31,30,31,30,31]*2)[:int(date[0])],int(date[1]))*1440+int(time[0])*60+int(time[1]))/525600
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>107 105</s>  102 bytes

```perl6
{$/=.comb(/\d+/);($0+(sum(|flat(-1,31,28,(31,30,31,30,31)xx 2)[^$1],$2)*1440+$3*60+$4)/525600).fmt: '%.5f'}
{$/=.comb(/\d+/);fmt $0+(sum(|flat(-1,31,28,(31,30,31,30,31)xx 2)[^$1],$2)*1440+$3*60+$4)/525600: '%.5f'}

{$/=.comb(/\d+/);fmt $0+(flat($2-1,31,28,(31,30,31,30,31)xx 2)[^$1].sum*1440+$3*60+$4)/525600: '%.5f'}
{$/=.comb(/\d+/);round $0+(flat($2-1,31,28,(31,30,31,30,31)xx 2)[^$1].sum*1440+$3*60+$4)/525600,.1⁵}
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{
  $/ = .comb(/\d+/); # grab a list of only the digits
  # ｢$0｣ is short for ｢$/[0]｣

  fmt

    $0 # year
    +
    (
      flat(
        $2 -1,                     #    days
        31,28,(31,30,31,30,31)xx 2 # -+ months
      )[^$1].sum * 1440            # /
      + $3 * 60                    #    hours
      + $4                         #    minutes
    )
    /
    525600

  : '%.5f' # the ｢:｣ is used here as ｢fmt｣ is a method not a subroutine
}
```

#### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
use Test;

# returns Str
my &fractional-year-a = {$/=.comb(/\d+/);fmt $0+(sum(flat($2-1,31,28,(31,30,31,30,31)xx 2)[^$1])*1440+$3*60+$4)/525600: '%.5f'}
# returns Rat
my &fractional-year-b = {$/=.comb(/\d+/);round $0+(sum(flat($2-1,31,28,(31,30,31,30,31)xx 2)[^$1])*1440+$3*60+$4)/525600,.1⁵}

my @tests = (
  '2016-08-06 23:48' => 2016.59723,
  '2013-03-03 17:34' => 2013.16912,
  '1914-11-11 11:11' => 1914.86155,
);

plan +@tests * 2;

for @tests -> $_ ( :key($input), :value($expected) ) {
  is-approx +fractional-year-a($input), +$expected, 1e-5, "a $input => $expected";
  is-approx +fractional-year-b($input), +$expected, 1e-5, "b $input => $expected";
}
```

```perl6
1..6
ok 1 - a 2016-08-06 23:48 => 2016.59723
ok 2 - b 2016-08-06 23:48 => 2016.59723
ok 3 - a 2013-03-03 17:34 => 2013.16912
ok 4 - b 2013-03-03 17:34 => 2013.16912
ok 5 - a 1914-11-11 11:11 => 1914.86155
ok 6 - b 1914-11-11 11:11 => 1914.86155
```